# Join two laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I have two Laravel collections. first collection $customer(It has 30 elements):

```
Collection {#2615 ▼
  #items: array:31 [▼
    0 => {#2610 ▼
      +"allocated_date": "2016-12-01"
      +"Customer": "44"
    }
    1 => {#2616 ▼
      +"allocated_date": "2016-12-02"
      +"Customer": "42"
    }
```

And other one is $agent(It has 17 elements)

```
Collection {#2586 ▼
  #items: array:16 [▼
    0 => {#2585 ▼
      +"agent_allocated_date": "2016-12-01"
      +"Agent": "41"
    }
    1 => {#2587 ▼
      +"agent_allocated_date": "2016-12-02"
      +"Agent": "95"
    }
```

I need the result like this (leftJoin allocated_date with agent_allocated_date). can not using merge or combine. because number of elements in both collections are different. help me to find the output

```
array:31 [▼
      0 => {#2596 ▼
        +"allocated_date": "2016-12-01"
        +"Customer": "44"
        +"agent_allocated_date": "2016-12-01"
        +"Agent": "41"
      }
```

Comment: what tie those 2 collections ?

Comment: dates
we can join on dates

Comment: then do a maping

Comment: i tried. but its not worked. can you help me on mapping

Comment: Please be more specific with what stumped you here. Just saying I tried mapping (and it failed) isn't going to motivate other people to help you. Show the code you've used. Show the mapping you've used. Give us the error message. etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to map over the customer and find the agent for that customer and merge the two collections:

```
$customer= $customer->map(function ($item, $key) {
    $single_agent = $agent->where('agent_allocated_date',$item->agent_allocated_date);
    return collect($item)->merge($single_agent);
});
```

Comment: Call to undefined method stdClass::merge()

Comment: glad to have helped

Comment: I'm on this way. This solved my question. And just curiously, will the solution costs huge server resources?

Comment: @Benyi depends on how many rows you return,if you return 2bil rows of coarse it will cost

Comment: @madalinivascu Thanks, I see. It doesn't matter even if it returns hundreds or thousands of rows. I didn't fell any latency when processing about 3000 rows.

Answer (score -1):

The better approach to execute join query.
I have tested this join query. It's working. Try this one.

```
$data = DB::table('customer')->select('customer.allocated_date','customer.Customer','agent.agent_allocated_date','agent.Agent')->join('agent','agent.id','=','customer.id');

print_r($data);
```

Comment: those two collections are coming from multiple join queries. I have the problem to join them